# Why is $\sum{\frac{1}{(j/2)!}(\xi)^j}\approx\sum{\frac{1}{j!}(\xi)^{2j}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation, quantum-mechanics

Why is $\sum{\frac{1}{(j/2)!}(\xi)^j}\approx\sum{\frac{1}{j!}(\xi)^{2j}}$?

This equation is used for solving the Schrödinger equation of the harmonic oscillator at one point in Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, chapter 2.3.2. 
He approximates the wave function (for great $\xi$) by $\psi(\xi)=h(\xi)e^{-\xi^{2}/2}$ and tries to find $h(\xi)$ using the power series $$h(\xi)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j\xi^j$$ and later he says $$h(\xi)=C\sum{\frac{1}{(j/2)!}(\xi)^j}\approx C\sum{\frac{1}{j!}(\xi)^{2j}}\approx Ce^{\xi^2}$$ and this is the point that I do not understand.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't $j$ the index of the sum? If so, I don't understand your question about "great $j$." If not, what is the sum over?

Comment: There is no such thing as "for great $j$" in this. The left side and the right side do not have $j$ as variables in that sense.

Comment: yes, the sum is over j. Forget that "great j" remark. Why is this equation correct? it's written in Griffiths "quantum mechanics" in chapter 2.3.2

Comment: maybe the index j has been shifted somehow by setting $j:=\frac{j}{2}$, but wouldn't this operation change the series?

Comment: @Clement C. The point is I don't see how you get the right side of the equation from the left one

Comment: I don;t see it either. More context may be helpful..

Comment: For large $\xi > 0$ we actually have $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(j/2)!}\xi^j} \approx 2 \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{j!}\xi^{2j}}$$

Comment: @Antonio This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you !

Comment: To add to Antonio's comment: more precisely one can show that $2\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}\zeta^{2j} = e^{\zeta^2}$ and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(j/2)!}\zeta^j = e^{\zeta^2}(1+\text{erf}(\zeta))$ where $\text{erf}$ is the [error-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).